# How to make work Django Window expression with SQLite?

Tags: sql, django, sqlite

I am testing Django ORM 'Window' SQL-wrapper capabilities.

I have following query in my code:

```
queryset = TripInterval.objects.annotate(
  num=Window(RowNumber(), order_by=F('id').asc())
).values('id', 'num')
```

which results in the following SQL query string (from debugger):

```
SELECT "request_tripinterval"."id",
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "request_tripinterval"."id" ASC) AS "num" 
FROM "request_tripinterval"
```

and is pretty straightforward. It **WORKS** when I copy/paste it into third party db-client. But Django ORM gives me an error:

> OperationalError
>
> near "(": syntax error

What is wrong here?

- System: Windows 10
- RDBMS: SQLite
- Django: 2.2.4
- Python: 3.6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your Python is using an outdated version of SQLite.

SQLite added support for window functions in [version 3.25](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_0.html), released in August 2018. Prior to that version, the exact same syntax error you're seeing would be thrown when trying to use window functions.

You can check the SQLite version used by Python by running this in the interpreter:

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

If the version that is output is older that 3.25, you'll need to upgrade your SQLite library version.

On a Windows system, the easiest way to do that is by installing the `sqlite` package from Anaconda. Otherwise, the general approach is to upgrade your installed system SQLite libraries, then recompile/reinstall Python. Alternatively, you could try installing the `pysqlite` package from PyPi.

Comment: I just upgraded to Python 3.7 and it seems to solve a problem.